# "This method is only meant to be run on single node. 0 found instead" Enzyme error

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, redux, chai, enzyme

I have a simple component that toggles sorting. When a link is clicked, it fires a function. When I run `shallow()` on it, I'm getting an error like

> Error: This method is only meant to be run on single node. 0 found instead

My component is:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { sortGames } from '../actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


class SortList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onSortGames = this.props.onSortGames.bind(this);
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        this.setState({
            sortByIncrease: false
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="sort">
                <span>Sort by:
                    <a href="#" onClick={e => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        this.props.onSortGames(this.props.filter, this.state.sortByIncrease);
                        this.setState({
                            sortByIncrease: !this.state.sortByIncrease
                        });
                    }}>
                        { (this.state.sortByIncrease) ? "Decrease" : "Increase" }
                    </a>
                </span>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

SortList.propTypes = {
    onSortGames: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    games: state.games
});
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    onSortGames(filter, asc) {
        dispatch(sortGames(filter, asc));
    }
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(SortList);
```

and here is my test script:

```
import React from 'react';
import {expect} from 'chai';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import SortList from '../components/SortList';
import configureStore from '../configureStore';

describe('SortList', () => {
    const store = configureStore();

    const props = {
        filter: "all",
        sortByIncrease: false,
        onSortGames : (a,b) => {}
    };

    it('should render sort list component', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<SortList {...props} store={store}></SortList>);
        expect(wrapper.length).to.equal(1);
    });

    it('should call sorting function when clicked', () => {
        const onSortGames = sinon.spy();
        const wrapper = shallow(<SortList {...props} store={store}></SortList>);
        console.log(wrapper.debug());
        wrapper.find('a').simulate('click');
        expect(onSortGames.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
    });
});
```

The `console.log(wrapper.debug());` statement prints

> `<SortList filter="all" sortByIncrease={false} onSortGames={[Function]} store={{...}} games={{...}} />`

What am I doing wrong? It has to be reaching the `a` tag, I believe, but still...

Answer (score 3):

I find out shallow can't find child elements on connected components, so they export component and connected component separately.
Here's how they do on redux examples [treeview example node component](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/tree-view/src/containers/Node.js)

so i changed my component like

```
    class SortList extends Component {
```

to

```
    export class SortList extends Component {
```

and

```
    export default connect(
      mapStateToProps,
      mapDispatchToProps
    )(SortList);
```

to

```
    const SortListConnected = export default connect(
      mapStateToProps,
      mapDispatchToProps
    )(SortList);
    export default SortListConnected;
```

changed my test scripts import to

```
    import {SortList} from '../components/SortList';
```

after that find() worked well.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a sinon spy but not introducing it into your `shallow` function. You need to pass `onSortGames` spy into props before you pass it to the component. As of right now when you click it is simply calling the function you listed in the properties in your `describe` clause `onSortGames : (a,b) => {}`.

Try directly applying the spy to the JSX, something like:

```
  it('should call sorting function when clicked', () => {
        const onSortGames = sinon.spy();
        const wrapper = shallow(<SortList onSortGames={onSortGames} {...props} store={store}></SortList>);
        console.log(wrapper.debug());
        wrapper.find('a').simulate('click');
        expect(onSortGames.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
    });
```

Comment: what happens if you change `shallow` to `mount`?